# Doctrine and Symfony: magic methods and caching

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm currently implementing the doctrine result cache so I've set

```
result_cache_driver: apc
```

into my configuration.

Then I've correctly got query cache working inside the Repository, using for example

```
->setResultCacheId(sprintf('posts_for_user_%d', $userId))
```

First problem come when I used these things in doctrine:

```
$repository->findOneBy(array)
$repository->findBy(array)
```

which can maybe easily overridden in the repository.

The problem which I can't get past is to use the ParamConverter to use doctrine caching and also entities association.

For example, if I have a Team entity with a OneToMany relation to Player I usually do

```
$team->getPlayers()
```

I don't have the control over the caching of that query. Is that possible in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run methods like find/findBy or process over PersistentCollection doing $team->getPlayers(), there is UoW which loads the data using EntityPersister and ObjectHydrator to hydrate an object. These objects have no support of result cache driver.

In the other hand, when you use DQL or QueryBuilder, your code products Query object that extends AbstractQuery. If you look inside AbstractQuery::execute you will see this pretty piece of code which makes using of result cache driver possible

```
$cache             = $queryCacheProfile->getResultCacheDriver();
$result            = $cache->fetch($cacheKey);

if (isset($result[$realCacheKey])) {
    return $result[$realCacheKey];
}
```

So my suggestion - try load your entities using QueryBuilder and leftJoins on children Collections.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('x')->select('x, p')->leftJoin('x.players', 'p')->....;
```

It'll create the possibility of using result cache driver.

Comment: Can you please explain what UoW means?
So the only way to correctly use caching and all its features I should implement the caching inside the repository functions?

Comment: UoW = UnitOfWork class. You should use result cache driver + Query object (produced with QueryBuilder or in a manual manner)

Comment: I'll just wait a few more days and in case of no new replies I'll accept your answer.